# Server Side Validation using PHP script

Tags: php, server-side

I have written this code for Form using `Server Side Validation` in `CORE PHP`

```
                if(empty($s_email)){
                $er = "Please enter E-mail";
                }else if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i", $s_email)){
                $er="Email-ID is invalid!<br>";
                }else if(!filter_var($s_secemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $er="Secondary Email-ID is invalid!<br>";


               <p>
                  <label class="required" for="s_email">Email Address:</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" id="s_email" class="half" value="" name="s_email"/>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="s_secemail">Secondary Email Address:</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" id="s_secemail" class="half" value="" name="s_secemail"/>
                            </p>
```

My problem is when I skip the `$s_secemail` field, I am getting this meassage
"Secondary Email-ID is invalid", its not mandatory

Comment: Use var_dump($s_secemail) to see what is in $s_secemail.If necessary use trim($s_secemail);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this only check `$s_secemail` is `valid email` or `not` if is `not empty` as the below code

```
if(empty($s_email)){
                    $er = "Please enter E-mail";
                    }else if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i", $s_email)){
                    $er="Email-ID is invalid!<br>";
                    }else if(!empty($s_secemail) && !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i", $s_secemail)){

                $er="Secondary Email-ID is invalid!<br>";

                    }


                   <p>
                      <label class="required" for="s_email">Email Address:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="s_email" class="half" value="" name="s_email"/>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label for="s_secemail">Secondary Email Address:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="s_secemail" class="half" value="" name="s_secemail"/>
                                </p>
```

Comment: @SagarPanchal i updated the code..you can check now..it is working in my system..

Answer (score 2):

use `else if (!empty($s_secemail) && !filter_var($s_secemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` to only check the condition if $s_secemail is provided

Comment: that's weird. are you sure `$s_secemail = $_POST['s_secemail']` ? you can also trim the data so white space will be truncated like this `else if (!empty(trim($s_secemail)) && !filter_var($s_secemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))`. Lastly, you're missing a `}` after the last if

Answer (score 0):

i found good source for implementing server side validation so would like to share
http://www.webexpertlabs.com/server-side-form-validation-using-regular-expression/

Comment: The linked site is no longer active (at least at the time of this writing)